# javascript, ie: xml with special characters, loadxml(xml) returns false

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, grails

I am sending a xml document with grails to the webbrowser and want to show parts of it.
However i get an error.
I debugged and the error was because of the special charakters like ü,ö a.s.o
In Firefox I dont have any problems, it works.
However Internet Explorer 8 doesnt load the xml.
I looked at the response, and saw, that it cannot get the ü,ö a.s.o correctly.
It gets rectangles instead of it ....

Here is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<IOX_Commands>
    <IOX_Device>
            <cmd num="4" name="Delete" value="msg" desc="Meldungen len"/>
        </IOX_Device>
<IOX_Commands>
```

Here is the grails part:

```
def get_Commands={
    //aus xml datei lesen:conf/IOX_commands.xml
    def file = "/conf/IOX_commands2.xml"
    def xmlfile = new File(file).text
    def xmlrecords = new XmlParser().parseText(xmlfile)
    response.contentType = "text/xml";
    render(xmlfile)
}
```

and here is the javascript part:

```
if (window.DOMParser)
               {
                    parser=new DOMParser();
                    msrctl_steuerworte_var.ioxCommands=parser.parseFromString(response.responseText,"text/xml")
               }
               else // Internet Explorer
               {
                    msrctl_steuerworte_var.ioxCommands=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                    msrctl_steuerworte_var.ioxCommands.async="false";
                    msrctl_steuerworte_var.ioxCommands.load(response.responseText);
               }
//....
```

When I try to validate the xml file at http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_validator.asp I get an error.

Can someone say how to fix the problem?
I already tried to make the file and the encoding UTF-8, but it doesnt help.
I think its either an IE config or i have to add something to the grails controller.

Answer (score 0):

> I already tried to make the file and the encoding UTF-8, but it doesnt help.

But it should. Just be sure to convert *the actual contents* into UTF-8 - just changing the header won't help.

Answer (score 0):

ok i think i solved a part of the problem with:

```
    def get_Commands={ //aus xml datei lesen:
    conf/IOX_commands.xml def file = 
    "/conf/IOX_commands2.xml" def xmlfile = new File(file).text 
    def xmlrecords = new XmlParser().parseText(xmlfile) 
    response.contentType = "text/xml"; 
    render(text:xmlfile,contentType:"text/xml",encoding:"ISO-8859-1")}
```